# Helm include map define in _helpers

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I try to include a map which is defined in the _helper.tpl file but I can't. I get the error "at : range can't iterate over"(nothing more).

values.yaml

```
services:
  - serviceX
  - serviceY
```

_helpers.tpl

```
{{/*
Define the mapping values
*/}}
{{- define "associated.resources" }}
{{- $resourceMapping := dict "serviceX" "config1" "serviceY" "config2" "serviceZ" "config5" -}}
{{- end }}
```

configmap.yaml

```
...
{{- $resourcesMap := include "associated.resources" . }}
{{- range $k, $v := $resourcesMap }}
{{- if (has $k $.Values.services) }}
   - $v
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

I don't really know how to set a map and include it then in my configmap file.  Does the include method support map type? It seems that it returns only string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving all logic to **__helpers.tpl** can solve the issue.

__helpers.tmp

```
{{/*
Define the mapping values
*/}}
{{- define "associated.resources" }}
{{- $resourceMapping := dict "serviceX" "config1" "serviceY" "config2" "serviceZ" "config5" -}}
{{- range $k, $v := $resourceMapping }}
{{- if (has $k $.Values.services) }}
  - {{ $v }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

configmap.yaml

```
{{-  include "associated.resources" . | indent 6 }}
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right. Better to change the logic to solve my issue.